# How to output with R Markdown in foreign languages?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I'm trying to write a document in Ukrainian/Russian using R markdown to output to a pdf, but the characters don't render. For example, my title 'Мова чи/или язык' just appears as '/'. Is there a package or setting that can accommodate foreign langauges?

Below is an example

```
title: "Мова чи/или язык"
date: "3/7/2021"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see your YAML header.

Comment: [This](https://bookdown.org/gorodnichy/utf8-markdown-problem/utf8-markdown-problem.html) may be helpful.

Comment: You could try [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246830/markdowns-bold-and-italic-stop-working-after-including-babel-package).

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to find easy way to do it. My suggestion is :

```
    title: "Заглавие по руски или българкси"
author: "Име"
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
  html_document: default
mainfont: Tempora
fontsize: 11pt
```